# save anonymous github gist with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, github, github-api, gist

I'm having trouble using `jQuery.ajax()` to post a gist to Github. The gist is created, and the response is `201 Created`, but the response tab in Firebug is empty and the error callback is hit.

```
  var data = {
    "description": "posting gist test",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
      "test.txt": {
        "content": "hello gist!"
      }
    }
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .success( function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
  .error( function(e) {
    console.warn("gist save error", e);
  });
```

Frustratingly, it works fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXpCV/

---

Maybe this is the issue. jsFiddle is getting different response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://fiddle.jshell.net
Access-Control-Expose-Hea...    Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  1093
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my `http://local.dev/` to https://github.com/settings/applications seemed to fix it.

Comment: not sure where one can add the URL. perhaps the UI changed since you provided this answer in 2012?

Answer (score 6):

Forresto's own answer is totally valid:

> Adding my http://local.dev/ to https://github.com/settings/applications seemed to fix it.

...but as long as this answer shows up when one googles for Gist+jQuery, it should have an explaination of what's going on.

Browsers have a security concern called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It forbids a web page to communicate with servers other than the one that page was loaded from, so this basically shouldn't work. There's a workaround technique called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) but it only works for GET requests while this example has POST.

Then there's this newer technology called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS). It allows pages opened in modern browsers to communicate with other servers using the good old AJAX.

GitHub API [only accepts](http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing) CORS requests from domains registered as OAuth Applications on GitHub. When jQuery sends a POST request, it sets the `Origin` HTTP header equal to the domain of the site it was launched from.

But i should say that for me the snipped worked out even with a jibberish `Origin` header. It worked and i don't know why. :)